# <i> element in nav-link <a>- can't turn off hover highlight

Tags: html, css

I've got a seemingly small issue I can't seem to correct no matter what I'm trying. This is a `navbar` problem with an  element displaying a font awesome icon, and shows a red text and yellow background when I hover over this icon. The  is outside the Dashboard but the Dashboard text doesn't highlight like the icon does. It abides by the `navbar` wishes. But the .fas or whatever is causing the highlights I'm trying to get rid of. Help me Overflow Kenobis. You're my only hope.

```
<li class="nav-item" style="">
  <a class="nav-link btn " method="POST" href="/users/dashboard" style="">
    <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt "></i> Dashboard
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Share the CSS code also

Comment: Would be good if you can share us your CSS code as well. You can add a code snippet or may be a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:hover` on `<a>` tag instead of `<i>` and remove the `:hover` from icon...

...If you can't find the `:hover` of icon you can apply `pointer-events:none` to the icon.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.nav-item a:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}

.nav-item a i:hover {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}

.nav-item a i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item" style="">
    <a class="nav-link btn " method="POST" href="/users/dashboard" style="">
      <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shared the proper was to do what I needed, though my issue was that the css values were set in a parent layout .hbs and removing these values got the desired effect. Jirka presents a good debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest inspecting it with Chrome Dev Tools / Firebug. When you select the element there is a tab with set of its CSS rules and you can figure out which css class causes the problem.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools css tab]

Hope it helps

Comment: You present a great tool for debugging.. I will need to keep this one handy. I found the issue further down the latter and it was actually literally set in the layouts hbs css altering the a i:hover, as I must've left it there when I was testing to see visual changes.